# What's the default server root path (CentOS7)

Tags: networking, centos

In `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` line 36 the ServerRoot is set.  Mine is :

```
ServerRoot /etc/httpd
```

But this returns a syntax error when I try to start `httpd` service.
Can anyone give me the default ServerRoot path?

Comment: Syntax error is not related to what value you assigned to `ServerRoot` directive. Can you give the full error message?

Comment: I don't have GUI in VM and can't copy form VM to host. But here's most: 
Loaded: loaded (/path/ enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code)
Starting apache http server
syntax error on line 36
invalid command 'Listen:' perhaps misspelled or defined by module.. Main proces exited.
Failed to start.
I can't find the Listen: anywhere in the /etc/htppd/conf/httpd.conf file, where else could this be?

Comment: @RobbertSegers: could also be in any of the files in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/`, in particular the SSL-related ones.

Comment: Error has moved to: "could not reliably determine the servers fully qualified domain name using localhost.localdomain. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message. I set the ServerName to the VM IP address but doesn't work. How do I set the ServerName Directive Globally?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax error is not related to the value you set to `ServerRoot` directive, your syntax for set `ServerRoot` is right. Run:

```
httpd -t
```

to check your configuration syntax.

For you comment, simply putting this line in your `/etc/httpd/conf/http.conf`:

```
ServerName localhost
```

You can see more details in [apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servername).

Comment: httpd -t returns syntax OK. Error on servername is solved. unable to open logs now, main process exited. Should I manually define log file paths somewhere?

Comment: @RobbertSegers: Yes, you should check apache user have permission to access and write log file.

Comment: Weird, I don't have an apache dir in /usr/local, shoudn't there be the log files? I found them in /var/log/httpd/error_log and did chmod 777 error_log, but error reproduces

Comment: It's actually not a permission isue. I think another process is using port 80, how can i determine which process this is or let apache listen to another port?

Comment: @RobbertSegers: You can change apache listen port by set new value to `Listen` directive. To find out what process is listen port 80, try `sudo fuser -v 80/tcp`.

Comment: Fuser command not found. Netstat tells me there is no process on port 80. In httpd.conf I put Listen:8080 and this gives a syntax error. Where and how to put this correctly?

Comment: @RobbertSegers: `Listen 8080` or `Listen 0.0.0.0:80`. Please read the documentation before have any question. And see the log file to know what caused apache exit.